# Reading a structured binary .dat file

Tags: file-read

I'm unable to read a binary  .dat file which is in the following structure :

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char message_code;
    unsigned char code;
    unsigned char sequence;
    unsigned char reserve_1;
    float ladle_weight;
    float tundish_weight;
    unsigned char reserve_2;
    unsigned char no_of_measurements;
    unsigned int  measurement_1;
    unsigned int  measurement_2;
    unsigned int  measurement_3;
    unsigned int  measurement_4;
    unsigned int  measurement_5;
    unsigned int  measurement_6;
    unsigned int  measurement_7;
    unsigned int  measurement_8;
    } message_metal;

 typedef struct {
    unsigned char message_code;
    unsigned char strand_no;
    unsigned char steel_code;
    unsigned char container_state;
    float water_pr_at_mould;
    float water_con_at_mould;
    float temp_diff_of_water_at_mould;
    float water_pr_at_common_intake;
    float water_con_at_section_1;
    float water_con_at_section_2;
    float water_con_at_section_3;
    float water_con_at_section_4;
    float water_con_at_section_5;
    float water_pr_at_section_1;
    float water_pr_at_section_2;
    float water_pr_at_section_3;
    float water_pr_at_section_4;
    float water_pr_at_section_5;
    float withdrawl_speed;
    float metal_level_in_mould;
    float bloom_length;
    } message_strand;

typedef struct {
     message_metal metal;
     message_strand strand[4];
     unsigned char hour;
     unsigned char min;
     unsigned char sec;
} machine;
```

The .dat files cannot be attached.

Comment: Is it a  binary file!

Comment: What platform is this on?

Comment: What code are you using to read these files and what language is it in?

Comment: package readints;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadInts {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DataInputStream input;
        input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream
        ("C:\\Users\\GIREESH\\Desktop\\M1.dat"));
        while (input.available() > 0) {
            int x = input.readInt();
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        input.close();
    }
}

Comment: @user3326492: please edit your question, using the code formatting tools provided, and delete the code in the comment above. As you can see it does not render well in this format.